# get the button that fired the event

Tags: java, android, events

well at school every week we are making a calculator each week on a different platform (wp7,javascript,iphone,android), today it's android, so i have a method that receives all the keystrokes and depending on the value of the key my class do something to get the value of the button in c# is the sender parameter , in javascript this , in android??

```
private OnClickListener leclicke= new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
    //get the id of the button that fired the click event
    //findViewById(R.id.???);
    } };
```

thank you.

Comment: use View.getId();
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private OnClickListener leclicke= new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
    //get the id of the button that fired the click event
     int id = v.getId();
    } };
```

then you must check if this view has an id or not using this

```
if(id == View.NO_ID){
//this view does not have an id 
}
else{
//the view has an id 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the method `getId()`

```
v.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same OnClickListener for all buttons, then you can do something like this:

```
Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

private OnClickListener leclicke= new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

       if(v.equals(b1)) {
         // handle button 1
       } else if(v.equals(b2)) {
         // handle button 2
       } // etc.
    } };
```

But this is a little clunky. Another thing you can do is specify a separate on click method for each method by setting the on click property for the button in the UI Designer, and then declaring that method in your `Activity`, e.g. `public onClickButton1(View v);`